# Check if string contains a uppercase letter "inside" it

Tags: c#, regex, string, list, .net-4.5

I am working on a filter for a wordlist.

So here are some example words, which are inside the wordlist:

```
var words = new List<string>();
var finalList = new List<string>();

words.Add("McLaren");//false
words.Add("Nissan");//true
words.Add("BMW");//false
words.Add("Subaru");//true
words.Add("Maserati");//true
words.Add("Mercedes Benz");//false
words.Add("Volkswagen");//true
words.Add("audi");//true
words.Add("Alfa Romeo");//false
words.Add("rollsRoyce");//false
words.Add("drive");//true
```

For this task I need a regex which only accepts letters(no special characters, no whitespaces). The words must contain at least 4 chars to unlimited. And it should only accept uppercase letters at start of the string. And this is where my problem is.

Here is my code:

```
var WordRegex = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]{4,}$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
var secondRegex = new Regex("([A-Z]{1})");

foreach (var word in words)
{
    if (WordRegex.IsMatch(word) && secondRegex.Matches(word).Count == 1)
    {
        finalList.Add(word);
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that the word 'lowerCase' goes into finallist which I don't want. I only want it going in to finalList if the uppercase letter is at beginning of the string.

My second regex is preventing words like 'McLaren' because it got two uppercase letters.

Again:

- McLaren <--- shouldn't accept (two uppercase letters)
- mcLaren <--- shouldn't accept (uppercase letter "**inside**"* string)
- **Mclaren** <--- should accept  (uppercase at start)
- **mclaren** <--- should also accept (no uppercase letters)

*What I mean with **inside** is if there are any uppercase letters not at start or at end.

The [previous version of my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202812/check-if-an-uppercase-lettter-is-inside-a-string) gave only C# solutions and now I want to have a regular expression for the same purpose, to learn from it.

Comment: You can use `^[A-Z]` to find an uppercase at the beginning of a string. Or even `@"^\p{Lu}"`

Comment: What problem is there with `^[A-Za-z][a-z]{3,}$`?

Comment: Why do you post that question twice? If the solutions provided did not work for you expalin why they did not instead of posting the same question again.

Comment: @HimBromBeere  Yes, I posted it twice. But have you seen any correct answer on my last post? no! SO says "If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or **ask a new question**."  So this is what i did. There aren't any useful answers on last posts! I don't get why everybody is so keen to mark questions as duplicate ? Think before you mark it!

Comment: Because you did not provide any information on why the provided answers do not fit your needs. Quite simple.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I admit that was my fold that didn't explain well, but I didn't even had a chance to edit my question! When I was starting to editing somebody already marked it as duplicate to an answer which was totally not the answer which i was looking for.

Comment: You might edit it anyway and ask for re-opening the question. Only because your question is a duplicate it is not ment to be deleted at all, it still exists and is editable to clearify or add some important information.

Comment: @deadpool_Y7 I have edited your question to make it different from your previous one. Now it is a new question, I can also reopen it. If you don't agree with the edit, just roll it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:[A-Z]|[a-z])[a-z]{3,}$
```

You can use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eB8xU8/2

Comment: thank you very much for your answer it works! really appreciate your help!

Comment: You know not to beg for accepting an answer. You have been here long enough to know that.

Comment: @PatrickHofman its not begging...its like closing the question...... a logical end to the question..........

Answer (score 3):

One regex suffices:

```
^[A-Za-z][a-z]{3,}$
```

- `^` denotes the start of the text,
- followed by one upper- or lowercase letter,
- followed by three or more lowercase letters
- followed by the end of the text (`$`), i.e. no other letters after the lowercase ones.

Answer (score 2):

This simple regular expression should do:

```
^[A-Za-z][a-z]{3,}$
```

It fails in there is any uppercase letter after the start. It allows at least 4 characters in total since the first part matches exactly one character, the second part at least 3. Combined it matched for at least 4.

Comment: @PatrickHofman thank you very much for your answer! it does work as well. Really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can take this Regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-z]{3,}
```

- The first one `^` is the start of the string
- `[a-zA-Z]`matches exactly one letter, no matter if upper- or lower-case
- `[a-z]{3,}` at least three lower-case letters.